# placing distinct random values refering to another column Excel

Tags: excel, random, distinct-values

I want to generate random String value that won't be repeated depending on the value in the another column. The dataset is fake and I need to complete segment name for every each customer. 
I put random names of segments this way:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;6);$Y$2;$Y$3;$Y$4;$Y$5;$Y$6;$Y$7;)
```

of course it doesn't take into the account that one customer can be placed only in one segment (in one of RANDBETWEEN value). Do you have any solution how to put a distinct value for every customer?

[image]

Comment: "one customer can be placed only in one segment": If this is true then why are Barry French and Carlos Soltero placed in two segments? According to your formula these placements were made manually.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: I used an advanced filtering in Excel, copied distinct data about customer, pasted random segment data. in the end I used another tool to join both spreadsheets.